# "Sorry, something went wrong" Error in Facebook When Loading Canvas App

Tags: facebook, facebook-canvas

Here's the situation: I have a canvas app made in Facebook that works fine on all browsers, including safari on iPad and iPhone.

My app is called 100 Places to See Before You Die.

The issue is with using the iOS Facebook App (the app on your phone that you use to access facebook). When you search for the app (100 Places to See Before You Die) and load it, it works fine. The issue occurs when a friend uses the share dialog to share the url to the app (http://apps.facebook.com/onehundredplaces/). If you click that link on the friend's wall from inside of the iOS Facebook App, you get a message that says "Sorry, something went wrong". The url in the window is apps.facebook.com/onehundredplaces/. If you click refresh, the app correctly proceeds to log you in and redirect to the mobile app url, which is http://www.listchallenges.com/100places/.

In my Facebook developer settings for the 100 Places app I have set the mobile app url to be www.listchallenges.com/100places/

I have searched all over the web for this and can't find anyone with a similar problem. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I have the same problem with an app I made, so you're not alone. But sadly I don't have a solution..